# Error : passing generated tuple to groupby function in pig latin

Tags: tuples, apache-pig

'data' file looks like

```
Column1 | Y
Column2 | N
Column3 |Y
Column4| Y
Column5|N

grunt> DATA = LOAD 'data' USING PigStorage('|') as (groupBy:chararray ,
condition :chararray);

grunt> FILTERED = FILTER DATA BY condition == 'Y';

grunt> GROUPED = GROUP FILTERED BY condition;

grunt> TUPLED = foreach GROUPED generate
FLATTEN(BagToTuple(FILTERED.groupBy));

grunt> describe TUPLED;

TUPLED: {org.apache.pig.builtin.bagtotuple_482::groupBy: chararray}

grunt> dump TUPLED;

(Column1,Column3,Column4)
```

When I try to pass this TUPLED to group by function 
getting below error 
cfl.txt input file data

cfl_code|book_code|country_code|start_date|end_date|cfl_type|amount
CFL_0001|159|US|2015-01-01|2015-01-02|I|100
CFL_0001|159|US|2015-01-01|2015-01-02|N|1200
CFL_0002|159|UAE|2015-01-01|2015-01-03|I|200
CFL_0002|159|US|2015-01-01|2015-01-03|N|2400

```
grunt> Load_cfl = LOAD '/user/hdfs/pig/data/cfl.txt' USING PigStorage('|') as (cfl_code:chararray,book_code:int,currency_code:chararray,start_date:datetime,end_date:datetime,cfl_type:chararray,amount:double );
grunt> grouped_data = group Load_cfl by (TUPLED);
2016-01-26 02:56:48,871 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: Pig script failed to parse:
<line 7, column 34> Invalid scalar projection: TUPLED : A column needs to be projected from a relation for it to be used as a scalar
Details at logfile: /home/hdfs/pig_1453794921782.log
```

Comment: Could you give some sample inputs as well

Comment: @SurenderRaja : updated my question with sample input data

Comment: You are trying to achieve grouping based on TUPLED which  is not a atom(column) of relation named Load_cf1. The Rule is Group statement look for one more atoms from Load_cf1 relation. That is the reason you are getting that error. It would be great if you can give what exactly the requirement based on your input

Comment: @SurenderRaja : Same my question also.. how can I pass dynamic generated tuple to the Group by function ?

Comment: It cannot be done, But still  if you want to send the complete relation to GROUP BY the don't use group by. just you can create  a java UDF and pass the entire releation to that UDF and inside that UDF you can do anything you want .